# android gradle failed to find the library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-gridview, build.gradle

I have an android project and want to add a library in my gradle but when build gradle says: failed to find ...

this is my library :

```
  compile 'com.felipecsl:abslistviewhelper:1.0.3'
```

and according to [this link](https://github.com/felipecsl/AbsListViewHelper) it is okey and should work.

I am very thankful if someone tell me what should I do, or suggest me another library with the same functionality. (I need this library to add a slideshow on top of my gridview)

P.S : I try another library for testing and gradle successfully build. so my gradle is okay.

thanks in advance

Comment: Are including Maven in your Gradle file?

Comment: @Motheus I don't think so, how should I include maven in gradle?

Comment: The library does not exist on maven: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|abslistviewhelper. This is a problem with the developer.

Comment: @NiekHaarman what about this link : https://maven-repository.com/artifact/com.felipecsl/abslistviewhelper/1.0.3

Comment: This is on a staging server: http://maven.apache.org/guides/development/guide-testing-releases.html

Answer (score 1):

You can only download the module "abslistviewhelper" from a repository if the author has uploaded it there

the maven repositories jcenter (https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter) and mavencentral (http://search.maven.org/) do not have "abslistviewhelper"

```
repositories {  
   mavenCentral()
   jcenter()  
}
```

Ask the author to publish his binaries to maven

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [Gradle documentation on repositories](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html). So, you should add Maven to your repositories:

Make sure you are adding this to your module build.gradlefile and not the project file.

In your buildscript try adding:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}
```

Then, before your dependencies are declared add the repositories:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work again, I think it doesn't exist at all :(

Comment: Then the library isn't in Maven :(

Comment: thank you very much, I send an email to author to push to maven.

Comment: mavevLocal() and the buildscript aren't necessary